# Javascript/jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make radio buttons that when you have them active, it displays a dropdown. I can already make it display, but when I click on another radio button, it shows one, but doesn't hide the other...
Code:

```
<input type='radio' name='op' onchange='$("#ban_length").fadeToggle();'/>
<input type='radio' name='op' onchange='$("#rank_list").fadeToggle();'/>
```

Comment: Are they members of the same `<form>` element?  Exclusivity among radio buttons with the same `name` only works if they are form elements of the same form.

Comment: Yes, they are members of the same <form>.

Comment: I would not use inline JavaScript if you already have jQuery.  Please show the rest of your relevant code here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript section:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#op1').change(function(){
        $("#ban_length").fadeIn();
        $("#rank_list").fadeOut();
    });
    $('#op2').change(function(){
        $("#ban_length").fadeOut();
        $("#rank_list").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type='radio' name='op' id='op1'/>
<input type='radio' name='op' id='op2'/>

<div id="ban_length">demo</div>
<div id="rank_list">demo</div>
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/b2UPt/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='radio' name='op' onchange='$("#ban_length").fadeIn();$("#rank_list").fadeOut();'/>
<input type='radio' name='op' onchange='$("#rank_list").fadeIn();$("#ban_length").fadeOut();'/>
```

Though I would suggest removing the javascript from the elements themselves, giving them `id`s and adding the javascript to a separate script with `$(theID).change(function(){...`.

Alternatively, you can use `hide` instead of `fadeOut` if you would like them to hide immediately.

And one last suggestion.  If there are many of these and not just 2, I would add a shared class to each of the elements you are fading in.  Then instead of `hide` on each element, just call `$(".className").hide()` to hide any that might be visible.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event only fires on the element that was clicked (i.e. the radio button that is now enabled). It isn't fired when a radio button is automatically disabled.

So you need to check all the radio buttons every time one of them triggers the `change` event. You need to be able to tell them apart, though, so start by giving them `id`s:

```
<input type="radio" name="op" id="radio_ban_length" />
<input type="radio" name="op" id="radio_rank_list" />
```

After that, you can use them to toggle the correct dropdowns:

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    if (id === "radio_ban_length") {
        $("ban_length").fadeIn();
        $("rank_list").fadeOut();
    } else {
        $("rank_list").fadeIn();
        $("ban_length").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you like a challenge or if you might have more than two radio's, you could use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to do something like this:

```
function getDropdownId(radioId) {
    return '#' + radioId.replace(/^radio_/, '');
}

var radios = $('input:radio');

radios.change(function() {

    // Checked radio's:
    radios.filter(':checked').each(function(){
        var id = getDropdownId($(this).attr('id'));
        $(id).fadeIn();
    });

    // Unchecked radio's:
    radios.filter(':not(:checked)').each(function(){
        var id = getDropdownId($(this).attr('id'));
        $(id).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Note that this method does rely on the id's of the radio buttons matching those of the dropdowns (e.g. `radio_ban_length` for `ban_length`).

---

Update: here is a **live example: http://jsfiddle.net/55ANB/1/**

Answer (score -1):

add id="ban" and id="rank" to your radios

in your jquery section, add the click handler to the radio buttons

```
$(':radio').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("id") == "ban") $("ban_length").fadeToggle();
  if ($(this).attr("id") == "rank") $("rank_length").fadeToggle();
});
```